# Incompatibility between Mocha and Expect (Jest) assertions in Node.js app

Tags: node.js, jestjs, mocha.js

I have been using Mocha as my test library and Expect for a long time. I just updated Mocha from (5.2.0) to the latest release (9.1.4).

Once I upgraded none of my tests send back an error with a declarative message instead the test simply timeout if the assertion fails. I tested different versions of Mocha and this starts happening for Mocha versions (>=8.X.X).

Example declarative assertion failure message before upgrade:

[image: Example declarative assertion message]

Timeout after upgrade
[image: Timeout after upgrade]

Should I migrate to a different assertion library? It's a pretty large project and I would prefer keeping the same assertion library but not being able to keep packages up to date is a deal breaker.

Does somebody know a fix to this issue? Or what may be causing it? Or should I migrate to a new assertion library?

Advice appreciated.

**Edit after further research**

Created a git repo which gave me a better understanding of the error.

When I use expect in a callback followed by a promise the assertion does not get taken into account and I get a timeout without the error message.

```
it('should fail another test', (done) => {

    request(app)
    .get('/test')
    .then(function(res) {

        expect(3).toBe(4);
        done();

    });

});
```

If I use the .end callback built into supertest the assertion works as expected with the line causing the error and comparison of the values.

```
it('should fail another test', (done) => {

    request(app)
    .get('/test')
    .end((err) => {

        expect(3).toBe(4);
        done();

    })

});
```

The http endpoint is just a basic placeholder endpoint.

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
     res.send({ data: true });
})
```

The code can be accessed here on GitHub: https://github.com/roodoodey/Mocha-Expect-Incompatibility

Is this intended behaviour which there is some way around? We often chain several endpoints together using promises but not knowing where an assertion error happens makes maintaining the tests a nightmare. This issue starts occurring for versions >= 8.X.X for Mocha.

Here is the complete code with endpoints and tests to illustrate this issue.

```js
const expect = require('expect');
const request = require('supertest');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.send({ data: true });
})

describe('Testing assertions', () => {

    it('should fail the assertion', (done) => {

        request(app)
        .get('/test')
        .then((res) => {

            expect(3).toBe(4);
            done();

        });


    });

    it('should fail another test', (done) => {

        request(app)
        .get('/test')
        .then(function(res) {

            expect(3).toBe(4);
            done();

        });

    });

    it('should fail another test', (done) => {

        request(app)
        .get('/test')
        .end((err) => {

            expect(3).toBe(4);
            done();

        })

    });

})
```

Here is the package.json, if you use mocha >= 8.X.X the issue where the line error is listed with the error does not work in asynchronous functions. For versions less than < 8.X.X it works just fine. I would really like to know how to solve this issue as the tests become useless if they cannot give me a descriptive error when they occur and the line at which they fail in asynchronous code.

```json
{
  "name": "mocha-expect-incompatibility",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha app.js",
    "test-watch": "nodemon --exec 'npm test'"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/roodoodey/Mocha-Expect-Incompatibility.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "node.js"
  ],
  "author": "roodoodey",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/roodoodey/Mocha-Expect-Incompatibility/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/roodoodey/Mocha-Expect-Incompatibility#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "expect": "^27.4.6",
    "mocha": "^9.1.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "supertest": "^6.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that causes the error?

Comment: Hey I added more information after digging around and an example project on github.

Comment: You should show a minimal, reproducible controller code you are testing

Comment: I've added the entire controller and the packa.json to illustrate the issue.